# Extract a map from a Json interprets all numbers as BigInt

Tags: json, scala, json4s

i've extracted a map from json. This works so far. As I don't know before parsing which fields are there in the json, I've been using a `Map[String, Any]`. Every field only consisting of digits is interpreted as a `BigInt`, which I don't want.

MyCode:

```
    implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    json.extract[Map[String, Any]]
```

Any way to implicitly make the numbers interpreted as `Int` or `Long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify, how the `json` value is created. If you parse it from a `String`, than the `useBigIntForLong` flag does the trick:

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.JsonAST._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val formats: DefaultFormats = DefaultFormats

    val parsedJson = JsonMethods.parse(""" { "a" : 42} """, useBigIntForLong = false)
    parsedJson.extract[Map[String, Any]].foreach {
      case (name, value) => println(s"$name = $value (${value.getClass})")
    }
  }

}
```

Output:

```
a = 42 (class java.lang.Long)
```

If you construct the json value programmatically, than you choose between `BigInt` and `Long` directly:

```
val constructedJson = JObject(
  "alwaysBigInt" -> JInt(42),
  "alwaysLong" -> JLong(55),
)
constructedJson.extract[Map[String, Any]].foreach {
  case (name, value) => println(s"$name = $value (${value.getClass})")
}
```

Output:

```
alwaysBigInt = 42 (class scala.math.BigInt)
alwaysLong = 55 (class java.lang.Long)
```

[Example source code](https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q53296953-json4s-bigint)